# Ajax success returns but no value is inserted in database

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello i am working with this html form:

```
<form action="" id="foo">

    <select name="selectOption" class="dropdown-select">
        <option value="">Select a day!</option>
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    </select>

    <input type='radio' name='group2' id='shampstyle' value='Shampoo-Style'>
    <label for='shampstyle'>Shampoo And Style-$50</label>
    <input type='radio' name='group2' id='relaxer' value='Relaxer'>
    <label for='relaxer'>Relaxer-$75</label>


<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary active">
</form>
```

And this is the ajax code:

```
<script>
            /* Attach a submit handler to the form */
        $("#foo").submit(function(event) {

        /* Stop form from submitting normally */

        event.preventDefault();

        /* Clear result div*/
        $("#result").html('');

        /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        $.ajax({
        url: "server.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
            if (data === "1") {

                alert('appointment recieved');
            };
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});

        //$("#showFrSent").fadeIn();
</script>
```

and server.php is simple like this:

```
include 'db.php';

$user_id = 1;
$selectOption = $_POST['selectOption'];
$radioVal = $_POST['group2'];

$newSql = "INSERT INTO appointment(user_id, weekday, service) VALUES ('$user_id', '$selectOption', '$radioVal')";


echo "1";
```

But the problem is success method runs and alerts `'appointment recieved'`but i see no data is inserted into the the database table. What could possibly go wrong here. I run the server.php on browser with hard-coded value and it can insert into the database. but when i run as ajax it fails to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not executing the query?

for example if you are using mysql use `mysql_query()`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO appointment(user_id, weekday, service) VALUES 
  ('$user_id', '$selectOption', '$radioVal')");
```

Comment: Why is one assume that this person is using the deprecated library?

Comment: coz he is not binding params or stuff like that so i assume

Comment: I love your faith. Perhaps misguided

Comment: We do not know what library this individual is using to access the database. You can do daft stuff in the more modern libraries like MySqli

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the SQL (and SQL injection is another tin or worms).

Are you using PDO, MySqli (or ...... ahh MySql) library